# How can I disable js in an input textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, input

I have input type text, when writing js in input field `<script> alert (1) </script>` it works, is it possible to disable js in input?
Thanks

```
<form action="" name="typing_and_press_form"  id="typing_and_press_form">
   <input id='typing_and_press' class="typing_and_press" type="text"
                               placeholder="<?php if($jobStrings)  echo $jobStrings['keyword_search']; ?>">
   <div class="tagsgroupkeyup"></div>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery('#typing_and_press_form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (jQuery('#typing_and_press').val()){
       var enteredValue = jQuery('#typing_and_press').val();
       jQuery('.typing-press .tagsgroupkeyup').append('<div class="tagstyle"><span>' + enteredValue + '</span><span id="' + enteredValue + '" class="remove">X</span></div>');
       jQuery('#typing_and_press').val('');
       jQuery('#typing_and_press').text('');
    }
})
```

Comment: An input box doesn't automatically insert and run HTML; you need to show the rest of the relevant code. In general you'll want to turn it into a DOM tree (by setting it as innerHTML of a newly created div), then remove all <script> elements before inserting it.

Comment: Try `.. '+ escape(enteredValued) + '...` : [MDN escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

Comment: There's no need for `id="' + enteredValue + '"` - your "remove" button/icon doesn't need a user-defined id, use the class for activating it.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a self-xss attack. Where the input is reflected onto the page, and executes javascript. To prevent this you have to use innerText, or you can also parse the input text by checking if there is any javascript in the input before showing it into the DOM.

In Jquery, you can use `.text()` method.

The Javascript part is:

```
jQuery('#typing_and_press_form').on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(jQuery('#typing_and_press').val()){
    var enteredValue = jQuery('#typing_and_press').val();
    spanElem = jQuery('.tagsgroupkeyup').append('<div class="tagstyle"><span></span><span id="' + enteredValue + '" class="remove">X</span></div>');
    spanElem.find("span:first").text(enteredValue)
    jQuery('#typing_and_press').val('');
    jQuery('#typing_and_press').text('');
  }
})
```

Comment: There's no need for an ID. Use `var newElement = $(html).appendTo('tagsgroupkeyup')` to keep a reference to the newly created div - or just `$(html).appendTo(".tags..").find(">span:first").text(enteredValue)` (or give it a class to find it ofc)

Comment: This is much cleaner/clearer than using `escape()` (upvoted)

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m . I didnt think about that. I have edited the post.